# Add id css via rails enum

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know I can set `id` via rails enum. For example,

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
            <tr id="<% #{index} %>" >
                      .
                      .
<% end %>
```

Comment: Those are not called as *enums* btw.

Comment: Just to put in my two cents, I find that in practice, you will want to use an id that is more unique than just the index. Imagine if you were doing this on the page with more than one model or having the same model on the page twice. JavaScript expects ids only to occur once (which is why you don't have the method `docuement.getElementsById` =D). At the same time, it may be better to use the product id instead of its index in the collection, since you may want to refer to it again. Anyway, consider at the very least making an id like `id="<%= "product_#{product.id}" %>"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly assign index to `id`

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
  <tr id=<%= index.to_s %> >
                  .
                  .
<% end %>
```

Comment: There is no need to call `to_s`, because `<%=` calls `to_s` internally when concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing *string interpolation* with *Rails tags*. You should do

```
<tr id="#{index}">
```

Or

You can also do

```
<tr id="<%=index%>">
```

Comment: according to ruby conventions, that's an unneeded interpolation :)

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I'm just stating OP how to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep you should add '=' right after <% like that

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
  <tr id="<%= index %>" >
 .
 .
<% end %>
```

or `<tr id="#{index}">`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to mix HTML and ERB tags and would prefer [`content_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) to generate the tag. Furthermore, there is the [`dom_id`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RecordIdentifier/dom_id) method in rails that returns useful unique ids.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= content_tag :tr, id: dom_id(product) do %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```